# He dropped it by accidentally

Tags: word-usage

He was holding a handtowel.

> He **dropped** it by accidentally.

Would "drop" indicate the mean of slip from hand on purpose?

Would it make people misunderstanding of using the word "drop"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, either

> He dropped it by accident.

or

> He dropped it accidentally.

but no, the verb "drop" does not imply anything about intentionality.  You can drop something accidentally or on purpose.